# Change permission to /proc/net/ip_conntrack on Ubuntu server 9.10

Tags: linux, ubuntu, permissions, ipv4

I have a script that needs to extract certain information form the /proc/net/ip_conntrack file once in a while. I do not wish to run this script as the root user.

Default permissions for the file is:

```
$ ls -lah /proc/net/ip_conntrack
-r--r----- 1 root root 0 2010-03-28 12:18 /proc/net/ip_conntrack
```

I can change it with:

```
sudo chmod o+r /proc/net/ip_conntrack
```

But that does not stick after a reboot. Is there some configuration file for file-permissions in the /proc directory in Ubuntu Server 9.10? Or do I just have to stick a chmod line in some startup script?

Comment: /proc is a virtual filesystem that resides only in memory. You should put your chmod line in a start up script.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it looks like you can safely stick the **chmod** command in rc.local (http://www.openbsd.org/cgi-bin/man.cgi?query=rc.local&sektion=8)

Comment: Will do. I just thought there might be some configuration files for the permissions of the virtual /proc file-system. No reason to loose sleep over this, thanks. :)